# Tezos - smart contract byte code to michelson

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, liquidity, dex

I am trying to figure out the SpicySwap swap fees. Since there is no public implementation available to my knowledge, I am studying the michelson code. For example:

https://tzkt.io/KT1NN1NgmKFTW5FUWiyxVjUt3kH9bCiqgxLW/code

Surprisingly, there seem to be no math operations in this contract, which is weird because it contains a swap entrypoint. The contract storage has a contract_code big_map, which might contain something relevant. In this map, there is a "finalize" key:

https://tzkt.io/KT1NN1NgmKFTW5FUWiyxVjUt3kH9bCiqgxLW/storage/19579

I would like to check this out, but the value is in "bytes" format. How do I decode this into michelson code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those bytes unpack to a lambda. You can deserialize the bytes by running the following command:

`tezos-client -E https://mainnet.visualtez.com unpack michelson data '0x<bytes>'`

Comment: Thank you, this worked nicely

Answer (score 2):

I'm the creator of SpicySwap and yes if you unpack the bytes in contract_code you'll find the lambdas with actual code. Not sure how useful they will be though.

For anything math related, just look at [UniswapV2](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol) pair contract. All the mathy stuff is exactly the same, but in a Tezos contract.

For example fees:

```
uint balance0Adjusted = balance0.mul(1000).sub(amount0In.mul(3));
uint balance1Adjusted = balance1.mul(1000).sub(amount1In.mul(3));
```

Spicy does the same thing.